# Replace shoot and retake button UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a simple way to replace the default shoot and retake buttons on a `UIImagePickerController`? I have my custom images ready and all I need is the shoot and retake buttton.

How can I use my custom images in place of the default ones? I currently have a camera overlay with guides for the camera I just need to replace the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that UIImagePickerController uses so much memory, an iphone 4 or 4s will give memory warnings if you do almost any conversion from UIImage to NSData. Having said this, you can solve your problem of replacing the shoot and retake buttons and have a better camera implementation by using AVFoundation. Here is a great example that is pretty straightforward:

http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/

and another:

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297

Hope this helps, feel free to ask me more about it.

Comment: Both the links have expired.